# findOneAndUpdate and send SMS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to send a text message notifying that a patient has checked in while updating the MongoDB collection appointment isCheckedIn: { type: Boolean } should be set to true.  I am using node js, express, ejs, and MongoDB. I am successful in sending an SMS message but not updating. How would I go about doing this?

```
//mogoose schema
var appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  lastName: { type: String },
  firstName: { type: String },
  phoneNumber: { type: Number },
  date: { type: String },
  time: { type: String },
  period: { type: String },
  isCheckedIn: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
var appointment = mongoose.model("Appointment", appointmentSchema);

//SEND SMS ROUTE
app.post("/:id", function(req, res) {
  const number = ***********;
  const message = "Patient has arrived for his/her appointment";
  nexmo.message.sendSms(
    "***********",
    number,
    message,
    { type: "unicode" },
    (err, responseData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData);
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    }
  );
});

// UPDATE ROUTE
app.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
  appointment.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { isCheckedIn: true },
    function(err, appointment) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        console.log(appointment);
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Solved the update route:

```
//UPDATE ROUTE
    app.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
      appointment.update(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        { $set: { isCheckedIn: true } },
        (err, responseData) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(responseData);
            res.redirect("/");
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: Your question only includes code for sending SMS. Can you also provide your code where you try to update your database?

Comment: Sure added route attempt

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `findOneAndUpdate`. Try below snippet

```
appointment.findOneAndUpdate(
 {_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)},
 {isCheckedIn : true }
);
```

Comment: Not working.  { isCheckedIn: false,
    _id: ********************,
    lastName: '*************',
    firstName: '*************',
    phoneNumber: *************,
    date: '*************',
    time: '2:00',
    period: 'pm',
    __v: 0 }

Comment: Are you using MongoDb ObjectId as _id? Can I have a sample id?

Comment: Do you have 2 route for post(“/:id” ? Please add console.log to first line of each route and give us the result

Comment: // UPDATE ROUTE
app.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
  appointment.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    { isCheckedIn: true },
    function(err, appointment) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/");
      } else {
        console.log(appointment);
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    }
  );
});

Comment: The update route is not console logging anything. This is what I get from the app.get("/") route : isCheckedIn: false,
    _id: 5bc417aebfa21e32bc82a0b7,
    lastName: 'doe',
    firstName: 'john',
    phoneNumber: 5454563456,
    date: '10/24/2018',
    time: '7:00',
    period: 'am',
    __v: 0 } ]

Comment: Do you send PUT request? Add `console.log('update requst received');` at first line of UPDATE ROUTE to determine that route work.

Comment: Got the update route working thanks! Is it possible to send an SMS and update isCheckedIn at the same time?

Comment: Fine, Yes you can do theses together, for example, first update, then copy and paste send sms code after it to send sms also, or if you want, if update done successfully, sent your sms in callback function

Answer (score 0):

```
//UPDATE ROUTE
    app.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
      appointment.update(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        { $set: { isCheckedIn: true } },
        (err, responseData) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(responseData);
            res.redirect("/");
          }
        }
      );
    });
```